# iphone viewport is dragged up and down

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, cordova, steroids

I am creating an android/iOS app through steroids/appgyver which is html and javascript coding. The problem is that on iphones (I think only on iOS 7) you can drag up or down the whole page/viewport as you can see in the image. I do not want this happens.

How can I fix it with css or javascript, but not with js touchmove because it causes me problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

within your project directory, open `www/config.ios.xml` and set `DisallowOverscroll` to `true` so it reads

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

that should do it for you :)